# How do I set multiple cookies for spring-integration http-inbound-gateway?

Tags: http, cookies, spring-integration

I'm trying to set multiple cookies in responding to an http-inbound-gateway in spring integration... when I attempt to set multiple "Set-Cookie" headers with an enricher, only the last cookie makes it back to the browser. What am I missing?

```
<int:header-enricher>     
  <int:header name="Set-Cookie" value="cookie1=abc" overwrite="false" />
  <int:header name="Set-Cookie" value="cookie2=xyz" overwrite="false" />
<int:header-enricher/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) this header should be in format:

```
Set-Cookie: <Name> = <Value> [ ; expires = <Date>] [ ; path = <Path> ] [ ; domain = <Domain> ]
```

So, there is no stops to do that in the `<header-enricher>`, but only within the single entry.

Since Spring Integration knows nothing about `Set-Cookie` semicolon nature it can't combine several declarations for the same header to the single entry. So, the last one wins.

The same rule for any header.

**UPDATE**

By the way we can do that already now.

The `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders` is a `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, so we can `add` several values for the same HTTP header and they will be populated properly to the `HttpServletResponse`.

Spring Integration's `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` can get deal with `Itarable` values from the `MessageHeaders`. So, we can just populate `Set-Cookie` header (SI header) as `List<String>` avoid that semicolon hardcore.

There is two ways to do that using `<header-enricher>`: POJO method invocation or `<script>`:

```
<int:header-enricher>
   <int:header name="Set-Cookie">
        <int-groovy:script>
            ['cookie1=abc', 'cookie2=xyz']
        </int-groovy:script>
   </int:header>
</int:header-enricher>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand this much better now.